# C# - Network path not found only on system startup

Tags: c#

When running file related methods of System.IO (like : **File.Exists or File.Copy**) from my code during normal execution, it runs with no problem. But when I put the built executable in Startup folder and restart, it always gives an error. On debugging, it gives 'Network path not found' error. But when I run it **not** through Startup, it runs well.

Please help me out.

Comment: Add some logging and log parameters to a file.

Comment: Please post some code, how in the world are we supposed to help if we have no idea what you're querying for in `File.Exists`?

Comment: Your network drives are not mapped yet when you try to run the code.

Comment: For me, network drives only get mapped the first time I access them in Explorer.

Comment: Change it to use UNC paths and you avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Server.MapPath(path) and see

Comment: Hi, can you please also provide the class, I mean System.Web etc... I am not getting class (.Net 4.0)

Comment: This (Server.Mappath) is for web projects, what kind of application have you built? (winforms, WPF, asp.net webforms, asp.net mvc, Console...)

Comment: Winform, sorry about that !

Comment: Then I think the comment by John Willemse (Your network drives are not mapped yet when you try to run the code.) is something you have to look into. I can imagine that the startup code is called so early in the boot process that the drive mappings are not there yet